# How to make a piece of javascript work only a given number of times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have the following code that scrolls 85px up and down a div by pressing buttons instead of using any scrollbars.

https://jsfiddle.net/e059ruzv/

But for some reason even after you have gone to the very bottom of the div pressing the down button takes you further downwards into undefined space. Similarly when you are at the very top of the div pressing the up button takes you a further 85px higher. Its like the div has infinite height both above and below the actual content of the div.

```js
var marginTop = 0;
var upHeight = 85;
var downHeight = 85;

$('.up').click(function() {

  var $elem = $('div>div:eq(0)');

  var currentOffset = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle($elem[0], null)['marginTop'].split('px')[0], 10);

  console.log('currentOffset', currentOffset);
  var result = currentOffset - upHeight - marginTop;

  $elem.css("margin-top", result + "px");
});

$('.down').click(function() {

  var $elem = $('div>div:eq(0)');

  var currentOffset = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle($elem[0], null)['marginTop'].split('px')[0], 10);
  var result = currentOffset + downHeight + marginTop;

  console.log('.currentOffset', currentOffset)

  $elem.css("margin-top", result + "px");
})
```

```css
div > div {
  transition: margin 0.05s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="up">up</button>
<button class="down">down</button>
<div style="width:125px;height:300px;overflow:hidden;margin:auto;">
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:red;"></div>
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:blue;"></div>
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:pink;"></div>
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:green;"></div>
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:yellow;"></div>
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:orange;"></div>
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:black;"></div>
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:brown;"></div>
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:purple;"></div>
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:grey;"></div>
</div>
```

Any help much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I mean if you're adjusting margins, then there *is* an infinite amount. There is no min/max to `margin-top`, so without any `if` conditions, it will just continue to move the contents up and down.

Comment: I would introduce 2 variables:
maxUp and maxDown
then check if maxUp === 0 in the '.up' bidning and if maxDown===0 in the '.down' binding and enclose the whole logic inside.
then after the condition decrease the value of the variable, and increase the value of the opposite action variable/

Comment: you know what would really help? A jsfiddle in an answer because I am pretty new to javascript all my knowledge comes from w3schools tutorials and whenever I try to edit javascript code I mess it up

Comment: @DanielH, I think he has not enough reputation to vote

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work.

1st get the inner max height(overflow) for your box container with

```
var maxHeight = boxContainer.prop('scrollHeight') - downHeight;
```

2nd check current scroll height use

```
var boxContainer = $('.container');
boxContainer.prop('scrollHeight')
```

For up, if `scroll height > than the box height` you can continue, otherwise you can't up anymore because it hit the bottom.

For down, if the `scroll height > maxHeight` you should not be able to go down anymore because you are at the top. if `scroll height <= maxHeight` you can go down.

```js
var marginTop = 0;
var upHeight = 85;
var downHeight = 85;
var boxContainer = $('.container');
var maxHeight = boxContainer.prop('scrollHeight') - downHeight;

$('.up').click(function() {
  if (boxContainer.prop('scrollHeight') > boxContainer.height()) {

    var $elem = $('div>div:eq(0)');
    var currentOffset = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle($elem[0], null)['marginTop'].split('px')[0], 10);

    console.log('currentOffset', currentOffset);
    var result = currentOffset - upHeight - marginTop;

    $elem.css("margin-top", result + "px");
  }
});

$('.down').click(function() {
  if (boxContainer.prop('scrollHeight') <= maxHeight) {

    var $elem = $('div>div:eq(0)');

    var currentOffset = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle($elem[0], null)['marginTop'].split('px')[0], 10);
    var result = currentOffset + downHeight + marginTop;

    console.log('.currentOffset', currentOffset)

    $elem.css("margin-top", result + "px");
  }
})
```

```css
div>div {
  transition: margin 0.05s ease;
}

.container {
  width: 125px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<button class="up">up</button>
<button class="down">down</button>
<div class="container">
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:red;"></div>
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:blue;"></div>
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:pink;"></div>
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:green;"></div>
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:yellow;"></div>
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:orange;"></div>
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:black;"></div>
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:brown;"></div>
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:purple;"></div>
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:grey;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to limit it by using if:

```js
var marginTop = 0;
var upHeight = 85;
var downHeight = 85;

var $elems = $('div>div');

$('.up').click(function(){
    
      var $elem = $('div>div:eq(0)');
      
      var currentOffset = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle($elem[0], null)['marginTop'].split('px')[0], 10);

   var test = (($elems.size() -2) * upHeight-10) * -1;      
       
      if (currentOffset >= test) {
      
        //console.log('currentOffset', currentOffset);
        var result = currentOffset - upHeight - marginTop;

        $elem.css("margin-top", result + "px");
      }
    });


$('.down').click(function(){

     var $elem = $('div>div:eq(0)');

  var currentOffset = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle($elem[0], null)['marginTop'].split('px')[0], 10);
    if (currentOffset <= 0) {
       var result = currentOffset + downHeight + marginTop;

      //console.log('.currentOffset', currentOffset)

      $elem.css("margin-top", result + "px");
    }
})
```

```css
div > div {
  
  transition: margin 0.05s ease;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<button class="up">up</button>
<button class="down">down</button>
<div style="width:125px;height:300px;overflow:hidden;margin:auto;">
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:red;"></div>
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:blue;"></div>
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:pink;"></div>
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:green;"></div>
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:yellow;"></div>
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:orange;"></div>
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:black;"></div>
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:brown;"></div>
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:purple;"></div>
  <div style="width:75px;height:75px;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:grey;"></div>
</div>
```

This also works if you add more divs.